# gfortran does not recognize comments in .h file that begin with 'c' in first column

Tags: fortran, comments, gfortran, freeform, fixed-format

I am trying to include a file 'a.h' into a Fortran program 'b.f'
The contents of the files are as follows:

a.h

```
c     This is a comment
      k = 10
 100  format( I5 )
```

b.f

```
program test_include
    include 'a.h'
    write(*,100) k
end program test_include
```

When I try to compile the file 'b.f' using the following command

```
gfortran -ffree-form b.f
```

The compiler gives the error

```
    Included at b.f:2:
c     This is a comment
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
```

But when I change the comment line to

```
!c    This is a comment
```

gfortran compiles it successfully and the program runs correctly.

Can someone tell me how to make gfortran recognize lines beginning with 'c' in a '*.h' file as a comment. I am trying to include a similar file (with comments beginning with 'c') from a library into my free-form fortran code, and I can't really make all the comments beginning with 'c' in that file, to begin with '!'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The include file is in fixed-form! You cannot mix free and fixed form in a single file. Since

> [the] effect of the INCLUDE line is as if the referenced source text physically replaced the INCLUDE line priorto program processing [,]

the combined source text needs to be either fixed or free form, but not a mixture of both. 
[Source: Fortran 2008 Standard, Cl. 3.4 (6)]

This leaves you two options:

1. Convert the main program to fixed form, or
2. Convert the include files to free form.

For 1), you need to specify `-ffixed-form`, and format `b.f` to comply to fixed form. `b.f` would then look like

```
      program test_include
          include 'a.h'
          write(*,100) k
      end program test_include
```

For 2) , you would convert the include files to free form. The include could then be written as:

```
!     This is a comment
      k = 10
100  format( I5 )
```

---

If you cannot convert all files, I would suggest writing wrapper modules in fixed-form, `include` the source code, and from then on `use` the wrapper modules instead. In case of the snippet you provided, this would require further thought, but in case of include files with only variables/parameters/interfaces this could look like

```
      module wrapper_vars
          include 'vars.h'
      end module
```

For subroutines and functions, you could also use modules:

```
      module wrapper_subroutines
      contains
          include 'subroutines.h'
      end module
```

Comment: So, in the free-form, lines beginning with 'c' are not comments. Got it. And the idea of writing wrapper modules, sounds right for my work. Thanks.